# MySQL/PHP - SELECT DISTINCT column based on another column with ORDER and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have a table named **messages** that is as follows:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
| id  | sender_id | receiver_id | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
|   . |         . |           . | ... |
|   . |         . |           . | ... |
| 120 |        19 |          11 | ... |
| 121 |         1 |           3 | ... |
| 122 |         9 |          18 | ... |
| 123 |         2 |           1 | ... |
| 124 |         1 |          24 | ... |
| 125 |         3 |           1 | ... |
| 126 |         7 |           5 | ... |
| 127 |        24 |           1 | ... |
| 128 |        25 |           1 | ... |
| 129 |         1 |          25 | ... |
| 130 |         7 |           3 | ... |
| 131 |         3 |           5 | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

How can I select the last 3 unique users that have communicated with User 1? 
In other words, how can I select:

- distinct sender_ids whose receiver_id is 1 **or** distinct receiver_ids whose sender_id is 1
- in descending order **and** limited to 3?

The result would look like this:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
| id  | sender_id | receiver_id | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
| 129 |         1 |          25 | ... |
| 127 |        24 |           1 | ... |
| 125 |         3 |           1 | ... |
+-----+-----------+-------------+-----+
```

or simply:

```
+----+
| 25 |
| 24 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

Test:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sender_id = 1 THEN receiver_id ELSE sender_id END user_id
FROM messages 
WHERE 1 IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY MAX(id) DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Nice how it outputs the sender_ids and receiver_ids as user_id. What if I want to include other columns in the output? Example: id, user_id, message, timestamp.

Comment: @amatek *What if I want to include other columns in the output?* Select `MAX(id)` in addition to current `... AS user_id`, use as a subquery for to select the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

`1 IN (a,b)` won't scale.  It will do a full table scan.  This will make use of indexes:

```
( SELECT id, receiver_id FROM messages WHERE sender_id = 1   LIMIT 3 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT id, sender_id   FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 1 LIMIT 3 )
LIMIT 3
```

together with both

```
INDEX(sender_id, receiver_id, id),
INDEX(receiver_id, sender_id, id)
```

Now, assuming you want the rest of the columns for the 3 rows:

```
SELECT m.*
    FROM ( ... ) AS x    -- put the above UNION inside here
    JOIN messages USING(id)
```

You have not said what your "descending order" is.  Perhaps `id`?  Perhaps a `datetime`?  `id` will be a little easier, so here goes:

```
SELECT m.*
    FROM (
            ( SELECT id, receiver_id FROM messages WHERE sender_id = 1
                  ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 3 )
            UNION ALL
            ( SELECT id, sender_id   FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = 1
                  ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 3 )
            ORDER BY id DESC  LIMIT 3   -- yes, repeated
         ) AS x
    JOIN messages USING(id)
    ORDER BY id DESC    -- yes, ORDER BY is repeated again
```

Discussion:

- Each side of the `UNION` can use an index to quickly find the requested row(s).
- `id` is assumed to be the `PRIMARY KEY` of `messages`.
- Each `INDEX` is "covering" -- all the columns needed in the `SELECT` are present in the `INDEX`.
- Changing from ordering by `id` to a datetime disrupts the "covering", but can be remedied.
- Getting 3 rows from each subquery, then chopping to 3 again -- necessary to allow for a variety of cases of who emailed whom and when.
- The final `JOIN` needs to look in the data's BTree only 3 times -- that is the goal of the "covering" and the initial "derived" table (the one with the `UNION`).
- For only thousands of rows, this complexity is not needed.  But if you have millions of rows, it is desirable.  For billions of rows, the complexity is essential.
- `OFFSET` gets trickier.  A discussion here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#or
- `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION DISTINCT` and seems to be appropriate in *this* case.  (A `message` from a user to himself will show up twice with `ALL`.)